# Azure AD B2C - Raising an error on AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress using a compare

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

My use case is that I want to raise an error on the TP AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress.

I tried using "UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual". That didn't work

Reading the documentation this must be derived from a self asserted TP which AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress isn't.

The other way would be to use something like "RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist" or "RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists" that throws an error if the claim is there or isn't.

But I want to throw an error like "RaiseErrorIfBooleanValueIsNotEqual" if the claim is not equal to a value. The claim will always exist.

Is there a way to do this?

**Update**

The first element of my user journey is:

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">                 
 <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="ReadEmailAddress"  TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" />
 </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Comment: Hi @nzpcmad. What is the data type of the claim type? Boolean or string?

Comment: Hi @Chris It's a boolean.

Answer (score 4):

This can be implemented using [the **AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue** claims transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/boolean-transformations#assertbooleanclaimisequaltovalue).

1. Declare the claims transformation:

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="AssertTheClaimIsEqualToTheValue" TransformationMethod="AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="your-claim-id" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="valueToCompareTo" DataType="boolean" Value="[true|false]" />
  </InputParameters>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

2. Invoke this claims transformation from the **AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress** technical profile:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress">
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertTheClaimIsEqualToTheValue" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

If the claim value isn't equal to the expected value, then an exception is thrown.

The self-asserted technical profile that invokes the AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress technical profile can display an error message for this exception using **UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual**.

Comment: Thanks. This is slightly different to what I've done so I'll take a look. One problem as per the updated question is that AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress is called directly as the first step. There is no self-asserted TP that invokes it. This whole flow is invoked by passing a JWT token using the client_assertion_type of jwt-bearer.

Comment: Hi @nzpcmad. In this particular case, if an exception is thrown from the **AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress** technical profile, then the user journey is terminated and an error response is returned to the relying party. Is this the desired behaviour?

Comment: Yes it is. What I can't figure out is where the error is displayed. At this point of the journey there is no form with text boxes etc. All it's done is AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress.